# Zero Ohmic resistance in superconductors is a little bit too enthusiastic?

Tags: electromagnetism, superconductivity

According to [this article](https://phys.org/news/2018-06-superconductor-geometric-frustration.html):

> Superconductors contain tiny tornadoes of supercurrent, called vortex filaments, that create resistance when they move.

Does this mean that our description of zero Ohmic resistance in superconductors is a little bit too enthusiastic?

Comment: are those stable structures under a DC load? or do you require an AC load to create and sustain them?

Comment: As a note: Type I superconductors do not show flux vortices (and type II superconductors do not show flux vortices below a critical field strength). Also superconductors in general have non-zero AC conductivities (which can, for example, be seen experimentally verified by the fact that they do not reflect light perfectly, or theoretically predicted by inspecting the London equation $\partial_t \vec j = \frac{n_s e^2}{m} \vec E$).

Comment: @lurscher In magnet wound from type II superconducting wires, the flux tubes are stable under a DC load, since they form simply due to the magnetic field. (That is the reason why all superconducting electromagnets are from type II superconductors – in type I superconductors the superconductivity would simply break down at pretty low magnetic field strengths).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that since superconductors were originally discovered because they exhibited electrical resistances indistinguishable from zero that zero electrical resistivity may have originally been the defining characteristic of a superconductor. But as more was learned about superconductors and the superconducting state it was realized that superconductors can exist in a mixed or vortex state consisting of normal-state vortices in a superconducting medium, and such a system can exhibit energy dissipation due to the movement of the vortices which results in an electrical resistance that is not strictly zero. So, yes, I guess you could say that the use of the term "superconductor" when these materials were first discovered could have been a bit "too enthusiastic" since it suggested that absolute zero resistance was an essential, defining characteristic of superconductors when it's not.

Not an expert in superconductivity and maybe someone else will chime in, but from my perspective as an experimentalist I would say that an operational definition of superconductivity is a very low electrical resistance combined with the Meissner Effect (i.e., magnetic flux exclusion).

Comment: To emphasize the role of the Meissner-Ochsenfeld effect for superconductivity: If we would have some impurity free conductor that does not show superconductivity as we cool it down, it would also reach zero resistance at $T = 0$. However, in contrast to a superconductor it would not expel a static magnetic field permeating the conductor before we cooled it down. A superconductor, in contrast, does expel (or confine to vortices) a not too strong static magnetic field when it is cooled below the transition temperature.